# Detecting whether an EventHub message has been sent

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-eventhub

I am working on an application that sends events via Azure Event Hub.
The task that sends the message is awaited, and I used ContinueWith to log that the event is sent.
When running with firewall rule for Azure, the event is successfully sent, but without the rule it is not. However, both situations produce the same console output telling me that the event is sent.

How can I tell if an event has successfully been sent to the Event Hub or not so that the program can do actions accordingly?

Code that sends the event:

```
try {
    eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
    Task t = eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
    await t.ContinueWith(delegate {
        log.Info($"Azure Event sent");
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > EventSender-exception {e.Message}");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you missing `async-await` with `ContinueWith`?

Comment: I am sorry, but not sure what you mean by that. The task is awaited, and the code is inside an async Task.

Answer (score 0):

This not an answer to the main question but, since the question was tagget `async-await` and the code does not follow the recommendations of not mixing old-style .NET 4.0 task APIs with `async-await`, here goes:

```
try
{
    eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

    await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));

    log.Info($"Azure Event sent");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > EventSender-exception {e.Message}");
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for making me aware of this. I guess this is a consequense of finding online solutions that are not always compliant with current standards - I'll take self criticism for that. However it does not answer the question, and I am afraid of missing messages due to connectivity issues without being able to handle that in a good manner.